# Parsesql find comparisons in nested statements

Tags: python, sql, parsing

I have the following problem, given a query like `select * where x <> 12;` I want to find all comparisons, in this case `x <> 12`.

The problem is that because of the recursive structure of the parsed query, this code will print `None`

```
import sqlparse

sql_string = 'select * where x <> 12;' 
print sqlparse.parse(sql_string)[0].token_next_by_instance(0, Comparison)
```

When using the flattening method on the list, the result is a list of tokens which do not provide the information needed to call `token_next_by_instance`. What ist the best way recursively search for comparisons in the datastrucuture created by sqlparse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
import sqlparse
def get_comp(stmnts):
   for i in stmnts:
      if isinstance(i, sqlparse.sql.Comparison):
         yield str(i)
      yield from get_comp(getattr(i, 'tokens', []))

sql_string = 'select * where x <> 12;'
print(list(get_comp(sqlparse.parse(sql_string))))
```

Output:

```
['x <> 12']
```

This will work on queries of any depth:

```
s = """
 select g.*, (select array_to_json(array_agg(i.type)) 
         from items i
         where exists (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(i.objects -> 'game_ids') v where v.value::text = concat('"', g.gameid, '"'))
         or exists (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(i.objects -> 'tag_ids') v where v.value::text = concat('"', g.tag, '"')))
 from games g;
"""
print(list(get_comp(sqlparse.parse(s))))
```

Output:

```
['v.value::text = concat(\'"\', g.gameid, \'"\')', 'v.value::text = concat(\'"\', g.tag, \'"\')']
```